# Troubleshooting 'rviz-9' Process Death via TeamViewer, Node Runs Fine Without TeamViewer

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

whenever i run the node via teamviewer? Without using teamviwer and running the node directly on the computer the node runs fine.

this is the error that pops up on my remote desktop:

```
REQUIRED process [rviz-9] has died!
process has died [pid 6774, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/...........
log file: /home/.........
Initiating shutdown!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302345/why-it-always-shows-required-process-%5Brviz-9%5D-has-died!--whenever-i-run-the-node-via-teamviewer?-without-using-teamviwer-and-running-the-node-directly-on-the-computer-the-node-runs-fine./) by [Jish](https://answers.ros.org/users/37317/jish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Teamviewer most likely interferes with your video cards ability to properly render 3D graphics.

That error is just about always caused by something wrong in the graphics pipeline, so that would be a good first thing to check.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0